# Found conflicting getters for name

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am a beginner in kotlin coding and I am trying to make a search bar with edit text which can find the user account from the fire-base. Here are my codes

```
    package com.example.videoapp

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.Editable
import android.text.TextWatcher
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.EditText
import androidx.core.widget.addTextChangedListener
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.videoapp.Adapter.UserAdapter
import com.example.videoapp.Model.Users
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.database.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_explore.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_explore.view.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_explore.view.recyclerView
import java.util.*
import kotlin.collections.ArrayList

/**
 * A simple [Fragment] subclass.
 */
class ExploreFragment : Fragment() {
   private var recyclerView: RecyclerView?=null
    private var userAdapter:UserAdapter?=null
    private var mUser: List<Users>?=null
    private var searchEditText: EditText?=null


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_explore, container, false)
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
        recyclerView!!.setHasFixedSize(true)
        recyclerView!!.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        searchEditText = view.findViewById(R.id.search_edit_text)

        mUser = ArrayList()
        retrieveAllUserd()
        searchEditText!!.addTextChangedListener(object :TextWatcher{
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
            }

            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
            }

            override fun onTextChanged(cs: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                searchForUser(cs.toString().toLowerCase())
            }
        })

        return view
    }

    private fun retrieveAllUserd() {
        var firebaseUserID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
        val refUser =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users").child(firebaseUserID)
        refUser.addValueEventListener(object :ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                (mUser as ArrayList<Users>).clear()
                if (searchEditText!!.text.toString() == ""){
                    for (snapshot in p0.children){
                        val user = snapshot.getValue(Users::class.java)
                        if (!(user!!.getid()).equals(firebaseUserID)){
                            (mUser as ArrayList<Users>).add(user)

                        }
                    }

                }
                userAdapter = UserAdapter(
                    mContext = context!!,
                    mUser = mUser!!,
                    isFragment = false
                )
                recyclerView!!.adapter = userAdapter
            }

            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
            }

         })

    }
    private fun searchForUser(str: String){
        var firebaseUserID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
        val queryUserd = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users").orderByChild("name").startAt(str)
            .endAt(str+"\uf8ff")
        queryUserd.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
            }

            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                (mUser as ArrayList<Users>).clear()
                for (snapshot in p0.children){
                    val user = snapshot.getValue(Users::class.java)
                    if (!(user!!.getid()).equals(firebaseUserID)) {
                        (mUser as ArrayList<Users>).add(user)
                    }
                }

                userAdapter = UserAdapter(context!!,mUser!!,false)
                recyclerView!!.adapter = userAdapter


            }
        })
    }


}
```

package com.example.videoapp.Model

```
class Users {
    var username:String = " "
    var Fullname:String = " "
    var image:String = " "
    var id:String = " "

    constructor()
    constructor(username: String, fullname: String, image: String, id: String) {
        this.username = username
        this.Fullname = fullname
        this.image = image
        this.id = id
    }
    fun getusername(): String{
        return username
    }
    fun setusername(username: String){
        this.username=username
    }
    fun getfullname(): String{
        return fullname
    }
    fun setfullname(fullname: String){
        this.Fullname=fullname
}

    fun getimage(): String{
        return image
    }
    fun setimage(image: String){
        this.image=image
    }
    fun getid(): String{
        return id
    }
    fun setid(id: String){
        this.id=id
    }


}
```

But whenever I am typing any word in the search its returning an error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.videoapp, PID: 4847
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found conflicting getters for name: getfullname
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:477)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.loadOrCreateBeanMapperForClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:329)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:430)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:231)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:79)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:203)
    at com.example.videoapp.ExploreFragment$searchForUser$1.onDataChange(ExploreFragment.kt:104)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:75)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:63)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:55)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
```

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kotlin compiler generates getters for read-only variables (getters and setters for read-write variables) defined in a class. Because you have a variable named `fullname` and custom `getfullname` and `setfullname` you will have two getters and two setters for `fullname` variable.

Here are all `get` methods you will see from Java code:

[image: all get methods in Users class]

And looks like `snapshot.getValue(Users::class.java)` does not know which `getters` and `setters` to use.

Simples solution should be removing custom methods:

```
class Users {
    var username:String = " "
    var Fullname:String = " "
    var image:String = " "
    var id:String = " "

    constructor()
    constructor(username: String, fullname: String, image: String, id: String) {
        this.username = username
        this.Fullname = fullname
        this.image = image
        this.id = id
    }
}
```

Otherwise, update variables declaration with `private` access modifier:

```
class Users {
    private var username:String = " "
    private var Fullname:String = " "
    private var image:String = " "
    private var id:String = " "

    constructor()
    constructor(username: String, fullname: String, image: String, id: String) {
        this.username = username
        this.Fullname = fullname
        this.image = image
        this.id = id
    }

    // Below are your custom getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir for helping me

Comment: But sir whenever I am searching accounts then its showing only some accounts not all accounts

Comment: @AbhinashMallick, That may be the issue of how you query data from Firebase. For example, are you sure you need `endAt(str+"\uf8ff")` in your search query? Try to remove it and test the result. The issue you had before was related only to parsing data.

Comment: still the problem is there. If I am searching Animesh then its returning Deva

Comment: Ask another question because the previous issue was solved. Wrong search results is a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need to declare your `User` class:

```kotlin
class Users(
    var username:String = " "
    var Fullname:String = " "
    var image:String = " "
    var id:String = " "
)
```

Getters and Setters are automatically generated by the Kotlin compiler.

Comment: Thank you sir for helping me

Comment: But sir whenever I am searching accounts then its showing only some accounts not all accounts

Answer (score 0):

Try to get rid of getters and setters and use [`data`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html) class:

```
data class User(
        var username: String = " ",
        var fullName: String = " ",
        var image: String = " ",
        var id: String = " "
)
```

Parameters of primary constructor, e.g. username, become [properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html), so you don't need to write additional getter and setter functions for them.

Comment: Thank you sir for helping me

Comment: But sir whenever I am searching accounts then its showing only some accounts not all accounts